# Pandas: Groupby.transform -> assign specific values to column

Tags: python, pandas

In general terms, is there a way to assign specific values to a column via groupby.transform(), where the groupby size is known in advance?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A':[10,10,20,20],'B':['abc','def','ghi','jkl'],'GroupID':[1,1,2,2]})

funcDict = {'A':'sum','B':['specific_val_1', 'specific_val_2']}

df = df.groupby('GroupID').transform(funcDict)
```

where the result would be:

| index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | specific_val_1 |
| 2 | 20 | specific_val_2 |
| 3 | 40 | specific_val_1 |
| 4 | 40 | specific_val_2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` can not accepted `dict` , so we can do `agg` with `merge`

```
out = df.groupby('GroupID',as_index=False)[['A']].sum()
out = out.merge(pd.DataFrame({'B':['specific_val_1', 'specific_val_2']}),how='cross')
Out[90]: 
   GroupID   A               B
0        1  20  specific_val_1
1        1  20  specific_val_2
2        2  40  specific_val_1
3        2  40  specific_val_2
```

Comment: Although it may sound silly, is there a way to split that into two lines (the sum and merge seperate)

Comment: @keynesiancross yes it has